# Render a JAR web applet from a byte array in Firefox

Tags: c++, applet, npapi

I have an assignment which involves developing an NPAPI (C++) plugin for an older version of Firefox. The plugin receives a decrypted byte array from an external library and renders the content on a webpage. The plugin so far works with images and various text files by utilizing NPAPI's drawing/window capabilities, however there is also an interest in allowing it to render JAR/WAR applets.

Unless I am mistaken, there is no way to "draw" a Java program with NPAPI, so it must be handled by Firefox. And since the plugin is dealing with encryption and decryption of secure content, it seems it would defeat the purpose to write the bytes back to a JAR file in the users browser.

Basically my question is this: would it be possible to stream the raw bytes of a JAR file from plugin to browser and have it execute on the browser without storing a temp file?

Comment: Welcome to SO - you should have a read of the help section on how best to ask your question; http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve You should include an example of what you have already done/tried.

Comment: I am meaning to ask more conceptually from someone with greater NPAPI experience -- would it be possible to stream the raw bytes of a JAR file from plugin to browser and have it execute on the browser without storing a temp file? I was hoping to find an answer to this before I spend time stabbing in the dark

Comment: apologies for misunderstanding the original question - your comment actually gave me a better idea of what you where after. Maybe you should edit your question to make it a bit more clear that that's what your trying to find out.

Comment: Made the original question a little less verbose -- thanks for the feedback!

Comment: @user3788685 MCVE? Great suggestion. Tip: `[mcve]` in a comment auto-expands to [mcve].

Comment: ahhhh thats how you do it ;) cheers I did wonder